# Function to operate on rows with column input

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe df:

```
df <- data.frame(var_1 = c("abcd","abc","ab"), var_2 = c("abcd","abc","ab"))
df$var_1 <- as.character(df$var_1)
df$var_2 <- as.character(df$var_2)
```

Say I want to blank the rows in var_1 which are under 3 characters, I would usually do this:

```
df$var_1 <- ifelse(nchar(df$var_1) < 3,NA,df$var_1)
```

Now say I want to turn this into a function so I can apply this to any column. I create the function that takes a column name as an input:

```
Func <- function(input_col) {
    df[input_col] <- ifelse(nchar(df[input_col]) <3,NA,df[input_col])
    df
}
```

However this does not produce anything when I run:

```
df <- Func(input_col = "var_1")
```

How can I create this function? Would I be better off using one of the apply functions here?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but let me point out that you can avoid lines 2 and 3 by adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as an option to `data.frame()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need commas:

```
Func <- function(input_col) {
  df[,input_col] <- 
    ifelse(nchar(df[,input_col]) <3,
           NA,df[,input_col])

  #return df
  df
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your columns are `character` columns you can do this:

```
df[sapply(df, nchar) < 3] <- NA
```

---

And if it's not ok to assume all columns are `character` columns, this should work:

```
d <- sapply(df, is.character)
short <- sapply(df[d], nchar) < 3
df[d][short] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use apply:

```
apply(df, c(1, 2), function(x){ifelse(nchar(x)<3, NA, x)})
```

kind greetings

Comment: `lapply` might be better here, e.g. `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(nchar(x) < 3, NA,x ))`

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

```
library(plyr)
is.na(df) <- colwise(nchar)(df) < 3
```